# Can I call multiple function on Vim startup?

Tags: vim

I frequently send files to Vim from Visual Studio. I have it set up as an external tool with the following parameter:

```
"+call cursor($(CurLine), $(CurCol))"
```

However, I also want to be able to call my own function as well. When I'm editing a file from VS I want the window to be large, so I expected to be able to do something like this:

```
"+call cursor($(CurLine), $(CurCol)); +call Embiggen()"
```

However, that doesn't work. I've tried a few variations (e.g. `, call Embiggen()`, etc).

Obviously I could write my own `PlaceCursorAndEmbiggen` function, but I don't really want to do that. Is there any way to call multiple functions on Vim startup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eureka!

Simply pass two strings:

```
"+call cursor($(CurLine), $(CurCol));" "+call Embiggen()"
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the solution would have been easier to find had you used the alternative, more commonplace syntax: `-c "cmd"` instead of `"+cmd"`. According to `:help -c`, you can pass up to 10 of these.

Answer (score 0):

These exact commands can be combined into one using pipe symbol:

```
"+call cursor($(CurLine), $(CurCol)|call Embiggen()"
```

. There are much more that can be combined this way, but some like `:normal` can’t, use @Ingo Karkat’s or your own answer for them. If you are short* on +commands and still don’t want to create a `.vim` file you can use either `:execute`

```
vim -c "execute 'normal! 1' | execute 'normal! 2'"
```

or (bash/zsh) `-S` with process substitution:

```
vim -S <(echo '
    normal! 1
    normal! 2
')
```

. Though most of time it is better to just create a `.vim` file.

* You can pass up to 10 `+` or `-c` (they are equivalent and they are not counted separately) and 10 other `--cmd`, though letter is less useful.